# Simplifying for-loop

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have a data :

```
    minval =  NaN   7   8   9   9   9   10  10  10  10
              NaN   NaN 10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
              NaN   NaN NaN 10  10  9   10  10  10  9
              NaN   NaN NaN NaN 9   9   10  9   10  10
              NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN 9   10  10  10  10
              NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  11  10  10
              NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  10  10
              NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  10
              NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10
              NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

and I do this following :

```
C=size(minval,2);
for e=2:C
    D1(1,e)=minval(1,e);
end
D1(D1 == 0) = nan;
for e=3:C
    for b=2:e-1
    D2(b,e)= minval(b,e)+D1(1,b-1);
    D2(D2 == 0) = nan;
    [D1(2,e), idx_bt(1,e)]=min(nonzeros(D2(:,e)));
    end
end
D1(D1 == 0) = nan;
for e=4:C
    for b=3:e-1
    D3(b,e)= minval(b,e)+D1(2,b-1);
    D3(D3 == 0) = nan;
    [D1(3,e), idx_bt(2,e)]=min(nonzeros(D3(:,e)));
    end
end
D1(D1 == 0) = nan;
```

It works well, it gives me a right answer like this :

```
D1 = NaN    7   8   9   9   9   10  10  10  10
     NaN    NaN NaN 17  17  16  17  17  17  16
     NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN 26  27  26  26  26
```

and

```
idx_bt = 0  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
         0  0   1   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
```

I guess there's a trick to make this code more simple and faster. Is there any help? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a "small" version of `minval` - maybe 10x10 and the output you get for this example. Usually it's harder to simplify code, than just rethink everything for a given input and output.

Comment: @sintyar Could you confirm the values of `idx_bt`? Running the code gets us `idx_bt` as the last two rows of the displayed results only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crux of the following code revolves around [**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which is supposedly one of the ways to vectorize codes.

**Code**

```
%%// Get C
C=size(minval,2);

%%// Declare variables to store required outputs 
D1 = NaN(3,C);
idx_bt = zeros(2,C);

%%// --------- STAGE 0 -------------------------
D1(1,2:end) = minval(1,2:C);

%%// --------- STAGE 1 -------------------------
ft1 = bsxfun(@plus,minval(2:C-1,3:C),D1(1,1:C-2)');%%//'
ft1 = [zeros(1,size(ft1,2)) ;ft1];
ft1(ft1==0) = NaN;
D2 = ft1;
[D1(2,3:end) ,idx_bt(1,3:end)] = nanmin(D2);

%%// Probably do not need this given your data, but if you have zeros 
%%// alongwith the NaNs and if you are looking to replace 
%%// those zeros with NaNs you might. So, it all depends on your data.
%%// This could be looked after later on in the code as well.%%//' 
D1(D1 == 0) = NaN;

%%// --------- STAGE 2 -------------------------
ft11 = bsxfun(@plus,minval(3:C-1,4:C),D1(2,2:C-2)');%%//'
ft11 = [zeros(2,size(ft11,2)) ;ft11];
ft11(ft11==0) = NaN;
D3 = ft11;
[D1(3,4:end) ,idx_bt(2,4:end)] = nanmin(D3);

D1(D1 == 0) = NaN;
```

Output

```
D1 =

   NaN     7     8     9     9     9    10    10    10    10
   NaN   NaN   NaN    17    17    16    17    17    17    16
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    26    27    26    26    26


idx_bt =

     0     0     1     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
     0     0     0     1     1     5     5     7     7     7
```

Comment: more information about `bsxfun` can be found in its tag wiki: [tag:bsxfun].

Comment: @Shai Thank you for the link! Let's promote `bsxfun`!

Comment: Thank you so much, this bsxfun really help me a lot.

Comment: @sintyar Could you edit your question with the correct values of `idx_bt`, as I am not sure of those?